# Deploying same microservice many times in my cluster to achieve faster performance

Tags: architecture, kubernetes

***Fairly new to containerized applications***

We're building an app via containers and when we deployed it to GKE, we're experiencing a slow performance when a microservice responsible of processing images and returning json results is taking at almost 30 seconds per call.

When we checked the utilization of the cluster, it's only showing around 1% of the CPU. This made us conclude that it was not a compute resource bottleneck.

What I want to know are the two following things:

- Would increasing containers of the same microservice help in accommodating more 'parallel' calls of the microservice?
- How can I optimize the container to take advantage of more computational power to speed up its processing?

Thank you!

Best Regards,
Mervinlee Tan

Comment: How does it compare to the performance when you run the container image locally (docker run) and then make an API call?

Comment: Hi aerokite, the program runs faster locally, around 1-3sec per recognition. Though, cpu usage is fairly high, which means the app is utilizing the resources properly. Is my presumption correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't experience a high CPU usage my guess is that you need to adjust your algorithm.

You can use a Kubernetes replicaset or deployment to run multiple instances of the same container and use a service in front of them to loadbalance request to each container instance.

Comment: Hi Lukas, do you have any sample of load balancing microservice I can use for studying the implementation?